# How to fetch the ListElement associated with the row which is clicked in a TableView in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `TableView` defined in my QML which will obviously have multiple rows populated by a `ListModel`.

I want to fetch the `ListElement` associated with the row which is double clicked.

I have my `rowDelegate` of the table view defined as such:

```
rowDelegate: Rectangle {
    color: "#D3D3D3"
    height: 30
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDoubleClicked: {
            console.log("table view row clicked...")
            // How to fetch the ListElement associated with the row
            // and return it for use by another module?
        }
    }
}
```

My comment pretty much emphasises what I'm looking for.

Comment: from the docs - _The model index is exposed as an accessible index property_ so you can get the element using [ListModel.get(index)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method)

Comment: @folibis thanks. How do I get the index of the row clicked though? Seems like there's scattered documentation around this, but it maybe just me.

Comment: See it [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#delegate-prop). index exposed to each delegate as well as `ListElement` properties. Just read the documentation well. Always start from the documentation! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't even need a `MouseArea` to handle the click in your delegate.

The `TableView` already has a [`doubleClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#doubleClicked-signal) signal that you can use to retrieve the model data from the clicked row index:

```
TableView {
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            name: "name 1"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "name 2"
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "name"
        delegate: Text {
            text: model.name
        }
    }

    rowDelegate: Rectangle {
        color: "#D3D3D3"
        height: 30
        // no MouseArea
    }

    // handle the click directly in TableView
    onDoubleClicked: {
        const element = model.get(row)
        console.error("doubleClicked on", element.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In scope of your delegate you can use `model` pseudo-property to fetch associated `ListElement` (or any other piece of data which is displayed via that delegate). You may think of it as a reference to original data item. It has all properties of `ListElement` (for example `text` or `color` or whatever) and also `index` property (index of item in your ListModel or any other model).